# Make Positioned Widget responsive

Tags: flutter, dart, position, flutter-layout, responsive

I want to make positioned widgets responsive but cannot find a way. I used media query but nothing is working. I know that there are many answers but I did not see anyone targeting positioned widget. Everyone doing row-column responsive. If you attach a simple example with the position it will be great. Here is my code.

```
  Positioned(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.87,
              left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02,
              // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 30,
              child: Text(
                'TRACK’R',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: check `CustomMultiChildLayout` - the docs say: *"CustomMultiChildLayout is appropriate when there are complex relationships between the size and positioning of multiple widgets. To control the layout of a single child, CustomSingleChildLayout is more appropriate. For simple cases, such as aligning a widget to one or another edge, the Stack widget is more appropriate."*

Answer (score 5):

Here is your `Positioned` widget inside a `Stack`. Isn't this what you want to achieve?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300),
          Positioned(
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.87,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3,
            child: ColoredBox(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
              child: Text(
                'TRACK’R',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 30,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Though, you might want to define your `top` based on the `height` of your screen instead of the `width`. Otherwise, your Text will be out of the screen in landscape mode:

[image]

Another way would be to use `Align` and `FractionallySizedBox` inside your `Stack`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(-.9, .9),
            child: FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: .3,
              child: ColoredBox(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
                child: Text(
                  'TRACK’R',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 30,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or, using a `LayoutBuilder` and then a `Positioned` widget inside your `Stack`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (_, constraints) {
          final width = constraints.biggest.width;
          final height = constraints.biggest.height;
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Container(color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300),
              Positioned(
                bottom: height * .05,
                left: width * .05,
                width: width / 3,
                child: ColoredBox(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(.4),
                  child: Text(
                    'TRACK’R',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: width / 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that help me a lot. Can you tell me more regarding the width which you are defining in Positioned width as well as when you use Fractionally Sized Box widthFactor: .3. Is it necessary?

Comment: It all depends on your requirements. It sets the width of your `Text` to 30% of the width of the Stack. If you provide more precise requirements, I could help you fine-tune the solution. Currently, for the `Align > FractionallySizedBox` and the `LayoutBuilder` solutions, I used 5% from both `left` and `bottom`, with a `width` of 30% of the `Stack`.