# How to make Positioned.fill responsive inside stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, stack, media-queries

I am using positioned.fill top value to adjust my text along with image. I am using mediaQuery for responsiveness. When I adjust it on larger mobile screen, then it cause same issue on smaller screen.

This is my stack code:

```
 Stack(children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (() => Navigator.of(context).push(
                    Transitions(
                        transitionType: TransitionType.fade,
                        curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        reverseCurve: Curves.bounceOut,
                        widget: detailinvest(title)),
                  )),
              child: Container(
                // height: 260,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    child: Image.network(
                      "https://arzenafees.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Invest_Rudn_Enclave.jpg",
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              // top: 255,
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      'Rudn Enclave',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.location_on,
                          color: Constants.colorMain,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                            'Adiala Road, Rawalpindi, Rawalpindi Cantonment, Rawalpindi District, Punjab, 46600, Pakistan',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 45,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ]),
```

Screenshot:
[image]

**Note: This UI was working good on smaller screen**

**Edit: My GridView code:**

```
body: GridView.count(
        primary: false,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        crossAxisSpacing: 12,
        mainAxisSpacing: 22,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 0.6,
        children: <Widget>[
```

Comment: Are you using this stack into the `GridView` ?

Comment: @JenisNavadiya yup

Comment: should I add gridview code?

Comment: can you use this text on image or inside the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GridView.count(
  primary: false,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
  mainAxisSpacing: 20,
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  childAspectRatio: 0.5,
  children: <Widget> [
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: (() => Navigator.of(context).push(
            Transitions(
              transitionType: TransitionType.fade,
              curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              reverseCurve: Curves.bounceOut,
              widget: detailinvest(title)),
           )),
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: Image.network(
                "https://arzenafees.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Invest_Rudn_Enclave.jpg",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text(
            'Rudn Enclave',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              color: Colors.black
            ),
          ),
          subtitle: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.red,),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'Adiala Road, Rawalpindi, Rawalpindi Cantonment, Rawalpindi District, Punjab, 46600, Pakistan',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 45,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]
    ),
  ]
),
```

[image]

Comment: no, I want it below the image

Comment: Then you simply need a `Column` i update the answer check that

Comment: I am getting bottom overflow exception at text

Comment: from updated code

Comment: yes from the updated code

Comment: check out the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10PpHROPQ5Fl8DFCoONLVB1mXZXv2E0Bx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you share your gridview code

Comment: try with Sizeconfig class for ui responsiveness.

Comment: remove `top` propertry inside `Positioned` widget

Comment: @SabahatHussainQureshi removed but not working, also I am getting incorrect use of parent data Widget

Comment: @SabahatHussainQureshi check out this answer , it maybe helps you to teach me how to implement that in my code, I was following the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66298349/make-positioned-widget-responsive

Comment: Now check i update the answer

Comment: The issue is with `crossAxisSpacing: 10,` `mainAxisSpacing: 20,` `childAspectRatio: 0.5,`. try changing them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247986/discussion-between-sabahat-hussain-qureshi-and-ali-punjabi).

Comment: @SabahatHussainQureshi it's working but let me check it on smaller screen phone and after that I will mark your answer as accepted

Comment: Okk check that mostly this issue occur becuase of `childAspectRatio`

Comment: @AliPunjabi Kindly check my Answer

Answer (score 1):

**This one working Fine :**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:page_view_builder_demo/configration/size_config.dart';

class TextFieldExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextFieldExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TextFieldExample> createState() => _TextFieldExampleState();
}

class _TextFieldExampleState extends State<TextFieldExample> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: [
          commmanWidget(
              "https://arzenafees.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Invest_Rudn_Enclave.jpg"),
          commmanWidget(
              "https://arzenafees.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Invest_Rudn_Enclave.jpg"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget commmanWidget(String img) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 10,
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  child: Image.network(
                    img,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(
              'Rudn Enclave',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  color: Colors.black),
            ),
            subtitle: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.location_on,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'Adiala Road, Rawalpindi, Rawalpindi Cantonment, Rawalpindi District, Punjab, 46600, Pakistan',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 45,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]